# Array display troubles in PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I am learning something new with checking for whether a username is used in the database and have created some code based on a tutorial I found online. I understand the logic, though not sure I have approached it the right way. In essence. Information is passed over from a form field. If what has been entered matches a field in the database then I want it to return / echo a result 'yes'. if it does not match, I need it to echo 'no'. Seems straight forward.

The tutorial is designed for predetermined values. i.e. 
$existing_users=array('test',''one','two',three');

Though I want the 'test',''one','two',three' to actually pull dynamically from a database.

So I went about adding the setting it up to do so, though the code I have written doesn't work when I try to place dynamic values in. My code is as below:

```
$existing_users = array();
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clients') or exit(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {$existing_users[] = $row['shortcode'];}

$arr = $existing_users;

$display = "'" . implode("', '", $arr) . "'";

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM 
    // If the code is written out as:
    // $existing_users=array('test',''one','two',three'); 
    // It works.
    // When the script is coded as below. It doesn't work.
    // Note. If I echo $display is displays 'test',''one','two',three'

$existing_users=array($display);

//value received from the get method
$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];

//checking weather user exists or not in $existing_users array
if (in_array($user_name, $existing_users))
{

//user name is not available
echo "no";
} 
else
{ 
//user name is available 
echo "yes";
}
```

I am not sure whether I am approaching this the right way because I am hacking an online tute, there potentially could be a far easier way. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: No idea why you are assigning a new variable `$arr`.

Comment: You are adding a string to the `$existing_users` array. Why are you doing all that converting and copying of `$existing_users` to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a faster way to do it:

```
$user_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients where shortcode like '$user_name'") or exit(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
    echo 'no';
else
    echo 'yes'
```

i didnt validate the input from $_POST tho

what tutorial are you following anyway??

Comment: i was just showing how to do it faster, even mentioned i didnt validate the input *sigh*

Comment: i should probably get familiar with mysqli

Comment: You should. Either `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You forgot the `i`, if you are doing it the modern way...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remake `$existing_users`, as you are already creating that array from database query

```
$existing_users = array();
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM clients') or exit(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $existing_users[] = $row['shortcode'];
}

$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];

if (in_array($user_name, $existing_users)){
    echo "no";
} else { 
    //user name is available 
    echo "yes";
}
```

and try to move your code to PDO

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database_db, 'username', 'password', array(ATTR::PDO_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE `shortcode`=:shortcode");
$stmt->execute(array(':shortcode' => $_POST['user_name']));

if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
    echo 'no';
} else {
    echo 'yes';
}
```